# Am I correct supposing that if an exception occurs inside a try block, following lines inside the try are never executed?

Tags: exception, scala

In the following example

```
try {
  lineA
  lineB
  lineC
  lineD
}
catch {
  lineE
}
finally {
  lineF
}
```

if an exception occurs (let's assume a 100% probability of an exception there) in lineB, then the total execution algorithm looks like

```
lineA  
lineB  
lineE  
lineF
```

lines C and D are never reached. Am I 100% right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're correct presuming exception thrown is of type caught in catch block